# jQuery solution for dynamically uploading multiple files

Tags: jquery, forms, file, upload

I have a form in which I am uploading pictures. I don't know how many pictures I may upload at a specific time. Are there any jQuery/AJAX solutions for dynamically adding a file upload field in a form?

Comment: are you only want to add file input field in form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple code for adding a file field in form using jQuery

```
<form id="myForm" action="your-action">

    <input type="file" name="files[]" />

    <a href="#" onclick="addMoreFiles()">Add More</a>

</form>

<script>
       function addMoreFiles(){

           $("#myForm").append('<input type="file" name="files[]" />')
       }

 </script>
```

Comment: nope... it doesn't solve the problem. (the little script above.) no inut field is added.