# Dynamically add new file upload input using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create multiple file upload with jquery "Next file" button.
I was thinking of simething simple like it was posted here: [jQuery solution for dynamically uploading multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633949/jquery-solution-for-dynamically-uploading-multiple-files)
but I have problems with naming.

I'm using a list of HttpPostedFileBase and my name attribute looks like this:

> name="FileList.File[0].Content"

I don't want to use Ajax and ask for View from server. I just want to append new line with input with correct name.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

My FileList model consist not only HttpPostedFileBase Content, but also select Type field.
Those fields after render look like this:

> select class="input-large" name="FileList.File[0].Type">...< /select>
>
> input name="FileList.File[0].Content" .../>

Those field are rendered in separate View using Html.Editorfor.
I want them both to be appended when "Next file" button is clicked.

Comment: What if you change it to `name="FileList.File[].Content"`?

Comment: @sroes I made edit to my post. When I do '[]' thing with select and input names, controller doesn't treat this field as object and ignores it. BUT when I statically add [1] to 'select' and '[]' to input name it does the thing.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20889987/219933) which I gave for a similar question yesterday. You can adapt it your own way.

Comment: You can upvote the answer if you think fit.

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I get enough reputation :)